# How to consolidate multiple LOG files into one .LDF file in SQL2000

Tags: sql-server, logfiles

Here is what sp_helpfile says about my current database (recovery model is Simple) in SQL2000:

```
name                          fileid filename                            size         maxsize    growth      usage
```

---

```
MasterScratchPad_Data     1      C:\SQLDATA\MasterScratchPad_Data.MDF    6041600 KB   Unlimited  5120000 KB  data only
MasterScratchPad_Log      2      C:\SQLDATA\MasterScratchPad_Log.LDF     2111304 KB   Unlimited  10%         log only
MasterScratchPad_X1_Log   3      E:\SQLDATA\MasterScratchPad_X1_Log.LDF  191944 KB    Unlimited  10%         log only
```

I'm trying to prepare this for a detach then an attach to a sql2008 instance but I don't want to have the 2nd .LDF file (I'd like to have just one file for the log).

I have backed up the database. I have issued: BACKUP LOG MasterScratchPad WITH TRUNCATE_ONLY. I have run multiple DBCC SHRINKFILE commands on both of the LOG files.

How can I accomplish this goal of having just one .LDF? I cannot find anything on how to delete the one with fileid of 3 and/or how to consolidate multiple files into one log file.

Comment: You might get more and better answers on Serverfault.com, where the SysAdmins and DBA tend to hang out more than here....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to use the ALTER DATABASE command, with the REMOVE FILE option. However, the file "cannot be removed unless it is empty", and I'm not entirely sure how you empty a log file--if the steps you've done don't do it, maybe detach and re-attach the database?

It's been some time since I've had access to SQL 2000, so I can't help much more than that.